# Show that $f(x) = mx+b$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to get a sold foundation on my understanding of topological continuity, so I want to make sure I can accurately prove some simple examples.

> Show that the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = m x + b$ for $m,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Using the definition of a function $f(x)$ as continuous at a point $x$ if for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $d_1(x,y)<\delta$ implies $ d_2(f(x),f(y)) < \varepsilon $ for all $y \in M_1$.

Finding $\delta$ as a function of $\varepsilon$ will show that such a $\delta$ exists. My assertion is that

$$
\delta=
\begin{cases}\left|\frac{\varepsilon}{m}\right| & \text{if $m\neq0$}\\
\text{any positive number in $\mathbb{R}$} & \text{if $m=0$}
\end{cases}
$$

The diagram below shows that if the distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than $\delta$, then the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ is less than $\varepsilon$.

[image: Diagram 1]

The diagram below shows that if the distance between $x$ and $y$ is greater than $\delta$, then the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ is greater than $\varepsilon$.

[image: Diagram 2]

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Yes your arguments are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the function $d(x_1, x_2)$ is the absolute value norm since we got $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. From what I learned in first-year calculus, a proper epsilon-delta proof form goes like this:

Assume $\varepsilon > 0$ and let $\delta = |{\varepsilon \over m}|$.

If $m \neq 0$,
 $$d_2(f(x),f(y)) = |f(x) - f(y)| = |(mx + b) - (my + b)| = 0 < \varepsilon$$
If $m = 0$,
 $$d_2(f(x),f(y)) = |f(x) - f(y)| = |(mx + b) - (my + b)| = |m||x - y| < |m||{\varepsilon \over m}| = \varepsilon $$
Thus, since $d_2(f(x), f(y)) < \varepsilon$ for all $m$, then by definition, $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|m||x-y|$. So te delta you suggested works fine!